# How to convert string into object property?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

I have a json data that has unknown objects like this:

```
var x = {
  "unknown1": 234,
  "unknown2": 324
}
```

I can get the properties name as:

```
var prop1 = Object.keys(x)[0];
```

Now I want to find the value of this property. I can obviously do `x[prop1]`, but I wanted to do `x.prop1`. My question is:

- What are ways to convert `prop1` into an expression so that I could use `x.prop1`?
- If `eval` can solve this then how and why would eval create security problems in this case?

Comment: Well, by nature of dot syntax, `x.prop1` will always give you the literal property "prop1" on the x object. So, unless you call the new property "prop1", you don't have a choice but to use bracket syntax.

Comment: As a follow up: I am really curious as to the reason why you do not want to use bracket syntax?

Comment: "I can obviously do x[prop1]" — *and you should* — "but I wanted to do x.prop1" — Stop wanting that. It is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: What's the reason for not wanting to use the right to for the job?

Comment: @DaveNewton Because I thought x[prop1] is taking `prop1` as string and there might come a situation where I might not have a method to use string as a variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @user31782 — Then the variable wouldn't contain a property name at all, so you'd have bigger problems.

Comment: @DaveNewton E.g. consider a situation where I am getting all my global variables from a json file. One variable suppose is `position` and I need `window.position` in my js code. Here I can't do `window[data.position]`. I know its a completely hypothetical situation but that was reason for asking this question.

Comment: Then you'd set window[varName] to the value. If your code relies on globals then you don't have an alternative-but you also seen to know what your code relies on, making it a non-problem. But as TJ says-it's more likely you're thinking about the problem incorrectly, and you should just use default JS mechanisms and avoid any trickery. I still don't understand the need for any of this if you're in control of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What are ways to convert prop1 into an expression so that I could use x.prop1?

You can't, without generating source code and compiling/evaluating it.

> If `eval` can solve this then how and why would eval create security problems in this case?

Yes, `eval` (and its close cousin `new Function`) can do this. It's only a security issue if what you're `eval`ing comes from an untrusted source. If you can trust that the value of `prop1` doesn't contain malicious content, then you can use `eval("x." + prop1)` to do this. Or `new Function("x", "return x." + prop1)(x)`.

But **there's no good reason to**. Just use `x[prop1]`. That's what brackets notation is for. It's normal practice, it doesn't have to fire up a parser and code generator, it's faster, and you don't have to worry about `prop1` having malicious code in it. If you use `eval` or `new Function`, it's **not** normal practice, it has to fire up a parser and code generator, it's slower, and you have that niggling concern in the back of your mind. So use `x[prop1]`. :-)

Comment: While not security issues, `eval` is slow and can do weird things with scope.

Comment: @Quentin: It's *slower*, sure; it's not slow in this day and age. No scope issue with `"x." + prop1`. But as I know we agree, there's just no good reason to use `eval` (or `new Function`) to do what brackets notation already does... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure I would even tell the OP that this is possible, lol.

Comment: @mhodges: The OP already knows it's possible, or is about to find out anyway, as they flagged up `eval`. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder At least the blood won't be on my hands.. xD

Comment: @mhodges: **:-D**

Comment: Could you explain why do `eval(x.prop1)` or `eval("x.prop1")` not work?

Comment: @user31782: `eval(x.prop1)` means "Get the value of the property named `prop1` (literally) from `x`, pass that value into `eval`, and evaluate it as code. So it would eval any code stored in a string in `x.prop1` (where `prop1` is literally the property name). `eval("x.prop1")` does what `x.prop1` without `eval` does: Get the value of the property named `prop1` (literally) from `x` (but slower, requiring firing up a parser and code generator).

Comment: @user31782: From the question and comments, it sounds like you're a fairly new JavaScript programmer. My advice is: Forget all about `eval` and `new Function`. Pretend they don't exist. The number of appropriate real-world use cases for them is extremely small and usually in the context of a fairly advanced system. Until/unless you're developing such a thing, don't use them. Use the normal JavaScript idioms, such as `x[prop1]`, instead. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As @mhodges says in his comment you could add a new property.

but it might seem redundant to do so.

```
x.prop1 = x[Object.keys(x)[0]]
```

Comment: Not to mention you're using bracket notation to define the property.. I guess if you really wanted to go all out, you should use `Object.defineProperty()` instead